# ContourPlot of a complicated function

Tags: plotting, graphics, equation-solving

I have the function $pot_1(x,y,z)$ which is given in analytical form. So, in order to plot the contours at the primary planes $(x,y)$, $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$, I use the following `Mathematica` code:

```
Clear["Global`"];
Off[General::spell];
pot1 = -Mn/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + cn^2];
V = pot1;
Vxy = V /. {z -> 0};
Vxz = V /. {y -> 0};
Vyz = V /. {x -> 0};
Mn=0.08;cn=0.25;
S1 = ContourPlot[Vxy, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False, Contours -> 20, 
ContourStyle -> Black, ContourShading -> False, PlotRange -> All]
S2 = ContourPlot[Vxz, {x, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "z"}, RotateLabel -> False, Contours -> 20, 
ContourStyle -> Black, ContourShading -> False, PlotRange -> All]
S3 = ContourPlot[Vyz, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, 
FrameLabel -> {"y", "z"}, RotateLabel -> False, Contours -> 20, 
ContourStyle -> Black, ContourShading -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

OK, so far so good. Now, I have one more function $pot_2(x,y,z)$ which is much more complicated than $pot_1$ and we can obtain its value only on specific points $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. This function is given by

```
pot2[G_, Mt_, a_, b_, c_, x_, y_, z_] := Module[{},
m[u_] := Sqrt[x^2/(a^2 + u) + y^2/(b^2 + u) + z^2/(c^2 + u)];
λ = If[m[0] > 1, u /. FindRoot[m[u]^2 == 1, {u, 1}], 0];
Δ[u_] := Sqrt[(a^2 + u) (b^2 + u) (c^2 + u)];
w000 = NIntegrate[1/Δ[u], {u, λ, \[Infinity]}];
w100 = NIntegrate[1/Δ[u] 1/(a^2 + u), {u, λ, \[Infinity]}];
w001 = NIntegrate[1/Δ[u] 1/(c^2 + u), {u, λ, \[Infinity]}];
w010 = 2/Δ[λ] - w100 - w001;
w110 = (w010 - w100)/(a^2 - b^2); w011 = (w001 - w010)/(b^2 - c^2); 
w101 = (w100 - w001)/(c^2 - a^2);
w200 = 1/3 (2/(Δ[λ] (a^2 + λ)) - w110 - w101);
w020 = 1/3 (2/(Δ[λ] (b^2 + λ)) - w011 - w110);
w002 = 1/3 (2/(Δ[λ] (c^2 + λ)) - w101 - w011);
w111 = (w110 - w011)/(c^2 - a^2);
w120 = (w020 - w110)/(a^2 - b^2); w012 = (w002 - w011)/(b^2 - c^2); 
w201 = (w200 - w101)/(c^2 - a^2);
w210 = (w110 - w200)/(a^2 - b^2); w021 = (w011 - w020)/(b^2 - c^2); 
w102 = (w101 - w002)/(c^2 - a^2);
w300 = 1/5 (2/(Δ[λ] (a^2 + λ)^2) - w210 - w201);
w030 = 1/5 (2/(Δ[λ] (b^2 + λ)^2) - w021 - w120);
w003 = 1/5 (2/(Δ[λ] (c^2 + λ)^2) - w102 - w012);
cc = 15/16 G Mt;
pot = -(cc/6) (w000 - 6 x^2 y^2 z^2 w111 +
  x^2 (x^2 (3 w200 - x^2 w300) + 
     3 (y^2 (2 w110 - y^2 w120 - x^2 w210) - w100)) + 
  y^2 (y^2 (3 w020 - y^2 w030) + 
     3 (z^2 (2 w011 - z^2 w012 - y^2 w021) - w010)) + 
  z^2 (z^2 (3 w002 - z^2 w003) + 
     3 (x^2 (2 w101 - x^2 w201 - z^2 w102) - w001)));
Print["pot2(x,y,z) = ", pot]
]
```

When $G=1$, $Mt=0.1$, $a=7$, $b=1.5$, $c=0.6$ and $-10 \leq x,y,z \leq 10$ I want to plot the contours on the three primary planes of the function $V(x,y,z) = pot1 + pot2$.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having replaced the `Print` statement in the last line of your module by

```
pot]
```

and defined

```
pot1[x_, y_, z_] = -Mn/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + cn^2] /. Mn -> 0.08 /. cn -> 0.25;
```

you just make a table out of it?

```
 datz = Table[pot2[1, 0.1, 9, 1.5, 0.6, x, y, 0]+pot1[ x, y, 0], 
 {x, -10, 10, 0.55}, {y, -10, 10, 0.55}];
 ListContourPlot[datz, DataRange -> {{-10, 9.8}, {-10, 9.8}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want all 3 slices

```
  datz = Table[pot2[1, 0.1, 9, 1.5, 0.6, x, y, 0] +
  pot1[x, y, 0], {x, -10, 10, 0.55}, {y, -10, 10, 0.55}, ColorFunction -> "Pastel"];
  daty = Table[pot2[1, 0.1, 9, 1.5, 0.6, x, 0, y] +
  pot1[x, 0, y], {x, -10, 10, 0.55}, {y, -10, 10, 0.55}, ColorFunction -> "Heat"];
  datx = Table[pot2[1, 0.1, 9, 1.5, 0.6, 0, x, y] +
 pot1[0, x, y], {x, -10, 10, 0.55}, {y, -10, 10, 0.55}, ColorFunction -> "Temperature"];
```

then

```
 {ListContourPlot[datx, DataRange -> {{-10, 9.8}, {-10, 9.8}}],
 ListContourPlot[daty, DataRange -> {{-10, 9.8}, {-10, 9.8}}],
 ListContourPlot[datz, DataRange -> {{-10, 9.8}, {-10, 9.8}}]} // GraphicsRow
```

does the trick

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I want. Why did you set z=3? Also I want to plot the contours of the sum pot1 + pot2 at the three planes not just pot2 for a single value of z as you did.

Comment: I think we are approaching! However, when I create the tables dtax, daty and datz I get the following error message

Comment: FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances....

Comment: that's because your potential is singular at the origin...

Comment: I am not sure about pot2 but pot1 does not have a singularity at (0,0,0) since the constant cn is always present and non zero. Anyway, how can I overtake this issue?

Comment: Neither pot2 is singular at (0,0,0). The module gives the value -0.0116815 at the origin. When I try to create the tables I get the above mentioned error message and I cannot reproduce your nice plots!

Comment: try and look at datx//Re ?

Comment: I think there is must be something else causing there error messages. Moreover, shape of the contours in not the expected one. At the (x,y) plane there must be an elongated barred structure parallel to the y=0 axis.

Comment: If your problem is one of evaluating an integral may be your phrasing was somewhat misleading?